# How to create a folder in a particular destination using batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory, mkdir

I am trying to create an empty folder at a particular destination. When I just run the command MD "C:\Release\test" it executes and creates a folder. however when the same command is in the .bat file along with other commands it doesnt seem to create any folder. Please help me with this

Comment: Can you show us (part of) your batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line works fine for me.  One way to force it to work is by changing your directory to C:\Release and then run the MD or mkdir command.

Comment: Thanks Zombian. It was of great help. :)